# object reference

Tags: java

```
class Forest {    

    void lion(){  
        System.out.println("king of the jungle");
    }

    public static void main (String a[]){
        Forest f = new Forest();
        f.lion(); //call 1
        Forest j = f;
        j.lion(); // call 2
    }
}
```

what is the difference between call 1 & call 2?
If object f is removed what happens in call 2?

Comment: removed how? If you simply make f = null after having put j = f nothing happens.

Comment: Try to follow the Java Naming Conventions (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: @Roflcoptr : ok..thanks for giving reference link..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. object will not be removed (as references are still active, the GarbageCollector will not destroy it)
2. The calls are the same (they both call the same method on the same instance of forest
3. Indeed, doing f=null; before j.lion(); will not have any apparent consequence

Additionally, get a tool like Eclipse that will issue warnings when you don't follow the naming conventions for Java. Better get used to it at the beginning.

Comment: I'm guessing that a 'learning' IDE might be more useful for understanding the concepts of objects, instances and classes. Eclipse is a bit too much of a jump for that, imo. I'd recommend trying BlueJ instead. Worry about naming conventions later.

Comment: public static void main (String a[]){
        Forest f = new Forest();
        f.lion(); //call 1
        Forest j = f;
        j.lion(); // call 2
    }

Comment: @Grundlefleck I can agree that Eclipse is not really good start. I think first you should try write simple programs without any IDE. But I dont think that worrying about naming conventions can be postponed. It is an import thing an if you learn it wrong it is difficult to get it right later. A lot of problems if working in a team is caused by people who don't follow naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between call 1 and call 2.  When `new forest()` is called a new `forest` object is allocated on the heap and initialized.  The reference to that object is stored in the variable you have declared `f`.  When you are initializing variable `j` to the value of `f` it is simply storing a reference to the same `forest` object in `j`.  Setting `f` to null would not cause the `forest` object to be garbage collected (deleted).  The `forest` object will not be garbage collected until all the references to it are nulled or go out of scope which would not happen here.

Answer (score 0):

1. Nothing.
2. Nothing.

Think of references like phone numbers. You can have several numbers assigned to your phone, but if you remove one, your phone still exists, and they can call you on all your other numbers. If you remove all of the numbers, nobody will be able to call you.

(But there's no burly Garbage Collector who turns up the next morning to destroy your phone, this is where the analogy breaks down.)

Answer (score 0):

Both calls invoke `lion()` on the underlying forest to which both `f` and `j` refer. If `f` is made to no longer refer to the underlying forest but `j` still does, then `j.lion()` will still work as expected.

The point to bear in mind here is that `f` and `j` are references to forests - the actual forests they refer to exist somewhere in memory. At the point at which there are no longer any references to an actual underlying forest, that forest becomes a candidate for garbage collection (note: it may not be garbage collected immediately). But as long as at least one reference to the underlying forest remains, that forest still exists. Here, making `f` no longer refer to the underlying forest still leaves `j` referring to it, so the underlying forest still exists and the call `j.lion()` will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

method lion() is invoked on the underlying object instance just the same. You can set f=null but the j reference will still remain on the instance.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

f calls it's own lion method, where as j calls f's lion method.

If f was set to null, then call 2 would throw an exception.